# Graphic output from Windows docker container

Tags: windows, docker, containers

my goal is to run Windows container with a desktop app (EXE) installed inside, having its own GUI (CAD).
It's not a problem to build the container, installing silently the app, however I cannot realize how its output (GUI) would be redirect/catch up in Windows docker host to interact with it.
Digging web I found DISPLAY envvar setting for Linux container, but nothing for Windows' one.
I cannot believe it's impossible to get graphic output from Windows Container.
Please help,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately docker containers are not designed for GUI using. It possible if only your app is accessible through web browser

Comment: Did you pay attention I used term "OWN GUI", i.e. no Windows GUI is needed here. Do you mean "no output besides text can be exported from Windows container"? I'd like to get some detailed "know how", ideas like X11 or any.

Comment: As per the comment above, there isn't a GUI on Windows containers. You can interact with Windows containers via a remote CMD or PowerShell session. If your app depends on GUI APIs, you can still have the app run fine, but you won't be able to "see" the GUI of a Windows container instance. More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/lift-shift-to-containers#what-cant-be-moved-to-windows-containers

Answer (score 0):

you need XServer, running on windows host machine

for example, install VcSrv https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/

run it, then see ipconfig in console
find vEthernet ipv4
[my ipconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi0Op.png)

use it when run docker container, for example try
docker run --rm -it --net=host -e DISPLAY=172.22.96.1:0 stefanscherer/xeyes

in env DISPLAY set your ipv4 from vEthernet in ipconfig